# How to set CSS value with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to change the background color of an HTML element whose ID is `foo`. I have this code at present:

```
var hexcode = new Array('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','a','b','c','d','e','f');

// this chooses a random value from the array hexcode
var ranval = function() {
    return hexcode[Math.floor(Math.random()*hexcode.length)];
}

// six ranval() are put together to get color
var colorname = "#" + ranval() + ranval() + ranval() + ranval() + ranval() + ranval();

// trying to put the value on the background of element with "foo" ID.
document.getElementById("foo").style.color = colorname;
```

This code is throwing this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
```

I'm sure that ID `foo` exists.

Comment: Are you positive? Where is your `<script>` tag (before or after the body)?

Comment: Not related to the error, but if you need to change the _background_ color you should use `style.backgroundColor` instead of `style.color`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple way to fix your code is:

```
var random_color = function() {
    function randomHex() {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * 15).toString(16);
    }
    var str = '#';
    for(var i = 6; i--;) {
        str += randomHex();
    }
    return str;
}


window.onload = function() {
    // For your body background color
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = random_color();

    // For your foo element TEXT color
    document.getElementById("foo").style.color = random_color();

    // For your foo element BACKGROUND color
    document.getElementById("foo").style.backgroundColor = random_color();
};
```

Answer (score 4):

Your error occurs because you're trying to access your element before the DOM is ready. Wait for the window to load before accessing it:

```
// Credit: http://paulirish.com/2009/random-hex-color-code-snippets/

function random_color() {
    return '#' + ('00000' + (Math.random() * 16777216 << 0).toString(16)).substr(-6);
}

window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("foo").style.backgroundColor = random_color();
};
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Blender/xQure/1/**

Comment: Your script will have errors @Blender, because if you get a number less then 6 characters the color wont change or changes wrong.

Comment: @SantoshKumar: Sorry, `load` should be `onload`.

Comment: @Blender still with the same problem, will not aways have 6 characters. You can complete it using RegExp, or use another like solution like what I did.

Comment: What if I want to change background color of body?

Comment: @SantoshKumar Use `document.body.style.backgroundColor = random_color()` on the `onload` callback

Comment: Is there anything that can replace `window.onload`? I think its creating problem in changing it every second with `setInterval()`.

Comment: @SantoshKumar: Put your `setInterval` callback in the `window.onload` function.